# Sangria simple graphQL query, but syntax error

Tags: graphql, sangria

I'm trying to implement a toy server with graphql endpoint using Akka Http + Sangria. However, when I send POST request with payload (direct cppy and paste from Chrome inspection)

> {"query":"query FetchPokemons($height: Int) {\n 
>   pokemonsWithHeight(height: $height) {\n    name\n 
>   }\n}","variables":{"height":100},"operationName":"FetchPokemons"}

The server gives error

> sangria.parser.SyntaxError: Syntax error while parsing GraphQL query.
>   Unexpected end of input, expected union, Comments, interface, scalar,
>   enum, type, inputType or directive (line 1, column 79): "query
>   FetchPokemons {\n  pokemonsWithHeight(height: 100) {\n    name\n 
>   }\n}"

But after checking graphql documents, there seems to be no reason why this query string would fail the parsing stage. This is my code to process http body.

```scala
def queryResult(request: Json, schema: Schema[Resolvers, Unit], resolvers: Resolvers)(
  implicit ec: ExecutionContext
): Route = { ctx =>
  for {
    queryJson <- Future.fromTry(Try(request.findAllByKey("query").head))
    queryAst  <- Future.fromTry(QueryParser.parse(queryJson.noSpaces))
    variables =  request.findAllByKey("variables").headOption.getOrElse(Json.obj())
    opName    =  request.findAllByKey("operationName").headOption.flatMap(_.asString)
    result    <- Executor.execute(schema, queryAst, resolvers, operationName = opName, variables = variables)
    res       <- ctx.complete(StatusCodes.OK -> result)
  } yield res
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually remove \" and \\n from

> "query FetchPokemons($height: Int) {\n pokemonsWithHeight(height:
>   $height) {\n name\n }\n}"

to feed

> query FetchPokemons($height: Int) { pokemonsWithHeight(height:
>   $height) { name }}

into the parser using

`def formatQuery(s: String): String = s.replaceAllLiterally("\\n","").replaceAllLiterally("\"", "")`

This solution is easy but unclean. I hope there was a better way - perhaps modifying queryJson.nospace?